# Regular expression validating html tags

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am trying to do one validation using regular expression, but still not getting success.

I need to validate on of my input which may be blank/empty. but If user has entered some value in it,

it must be validate following validations.

```
1. maximum 20 characters allows.
2. allowed [a-zA-Z0-9], but first character must be a latter (e.g. A-Z (any case))
3. do not allowed html tags.
```

thanks.

Comment: Send me ur current source

Comment: Here is a suggestion: learn about regex.

Comment: escaping characters like <, > to html entities might be a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
\b(^\D{1}[[:alnum:]]+){0,20}\b
```

it will satisfy your condition

[check here](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3Lt)

Comment: thanks @user3064914, but it is not working. I have written as follows in my backbone model validation. /^(^\D{1}[[:alnum:]]+){0,20}*$/ It is giving me error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(^\D{1}[[:alnum:]]+){0,20}*$/: Nothing to repeat" How do I test on http://www.phpliveregex.com

Comment: it is working fine in phpregex click the link to see the result

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
/^(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,19})?$/
```

Comment: this works and will give a result for empty values as well. But whats with the '?:' at the start? it should work without these right?

Comment: @martijn: `(?:...)` means a non-capture group it's used when you want to group data but don't need to capture it.